Visual Studio C# SerialPort receiving ASCII convert to normal character
Sorry I'm newbie in C# windows app to serial hardware. I'm having a hard time and already tried all of my possible resources.
Problem is I'm receiving ASCII response in a machine using serial. This is the sample code.
            dataCode = textBox1.Text;
            serialPort1.Write(dataCode);
            dataReceived = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
            textBox2.Text = dataReceived;

            byte[] rawData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serialPort1.ReadExisting());
            string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rawData);

            byte[] rawData1 = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(dataReceived);
            string data1 = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(rawData1);
            if (data.StartsWith("1"))
            {
                data = data.Substring(1);
            }
            BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                textBox2.AppendText(data);
                LogData("System Received - Code: ", dataReceived);
            });
            LogData("System Received - Code1: ", data);
            LogData("System Received - Code2: ", data1);
            MessageBox.Show(data);
            MessageBox.Show(data1);

Note: the following order data code is hex except special explanation.
this is the sample code that i send
Peripheral computer sends：A0H+mode code（1byte）+verification code（1byte）
Instrument response： A0H+verification code（1byte）
Any suggestion would be a great help
Im expecting a result will be not ASCII

You should use Read method instead of ReadExisting when reading binary data.

@SherifElmetainy already tried also DetaReceived format same response. Do you have sample code for reading or converting binary data ? Thanks

I recommend reading all of the SerialPort documentation. It's important to match the settings of the serial port device. The following may be of interest: Encoding.

Note on tags. I'm about 99% sure you are using neither C# v3.0 nor 4.0 (released in 2008 and 2010 respectively, IIRC). It also looks like WinForms code, not ASP.NET code. Accurate tagging of tour question can really help in getting better answers
